# Change option in select tag from another select

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to change options of my second select depending on what I chose from the first select. Once again, I know where my code should be, I know that I need a if statement, and many if else but I am stuck in php now. If I select "Acura" I want, for example, my $modele_acura shows up in my second select tag.

(Thanks to all of you, many beginner programmers, as myself, should be so thankfully for all of your help guys, thanks in advance!)

```
<?php
$marques = array(
    'Acura',
    'Aston Martin',
    'Audi',
    'Bentley',
    'BMW',
    'Buick',
    'Cadillac',
    'Chevrolet',
    'Chrysler',
    'Dodge',
    'Ferrari',
    'Fiat',
    'Ford',
    'GMC',
    'Honda',
    'Hyundai',
    'Infiniti',
    'Jaguar',
    'Jeep',
    'Kia',
    'Lamborghini',
    'Land Rover',
    'Lexus',
    'Lincoln',
    'Lotus',
    'Mazda',
    'Mercedes-Benz',
    'MINI',
    'Mitsubishi',
    'Nissan',
    'Pontiac',
    'Porsche',
    'Ram',
    'Saab',
    'Saturn',
    'Scion',
    'Smart',
    'Subaru',
    'Suzuki',
    'Toyota',
    'Volkswagen',
    'Volvo'
    );

    $modele_acura = array(
    '1',
    '2',
    );

    $modele_aston = array(
    '3',
    '4',
    );
?>

<body>
    <form action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
        <select id="marque" name="marque">
            <option></option>
            <?php
            foreach($marques as $marque => $value)
            {
                echo '<option value="'.$marque.'">'.$value.' </option>';
            }
            ?>
        </select>
        <select>
            <option></option>
            <?php
                echo '<option value=""></option>';
                            // I AM STUCK HERE :(
            ?>
        </select>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: You can't access PHP variables from Javascript.

Comment: you can make use of ajax for this. you can bind the first select tags change event and send an ajax call with the selected options value. And from your php file echo out the matching options.

Answer (score 2):

Change your `$modele_XXX` arrays to a single associative array:

```
$modele = array('acura' => array(1, 2),
                'aston' => array(3, 4),
                ...
                );
```

Change your HTML to:

```
<body>
    <form action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
        <select id="marque" name="marque">
            <option></option>
            <?php
            foreach($marques as $marque => $value)
            {
                echo '<option value="'.$marque.'">'.$value.' </option>';
            }
            ?>
        </select>
        <select id="modele" name="modele">
        </select>
    </form>
</body>
```

And add this jQuery code to your PHP script, sometime after assigning `$modele` above.

```
$(function() {
    var modele = <?php echo json_encode($modele); ?>; // Convert PHP array to Javascript
    $("#marque").change(function() {
        $("#modele").html("<option/>"); // Initial empty value
        var selected_modele = $(this).val();
        if (selected_modele) {
            var modele_vals = modele[selected_modele.toLowerCase()];
            $.each(modele_vals, function(i, elem) {
                $("#modele").append($("<option/>", { value: elem, text: elem }));
            });
        }
    });
});
```